# Laravel Storage::get() doesn't find my files

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function where I want to delete my uploaded images, but this function of laravel cant find my files...

```
$file = Storage::get('/images/catalog/'. $product->sku .'.jpg');
```

The path on windows explorer is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\Laravel\Projects\energy-source\public\images\catalog\1.jpg
```

If I run this code I get the image display in the browser

```
echo '<img src="/images/catalog/' . $product->sku . '.jpg"/>';
```

Comment: you can try: `Storage::get(public_path() . '/images/catalog/' . $product->sku .'.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

```
\File::delete(public_path().'/images/catalog/' . $product->sku . '.jpg');
```

***Forward slashes gives errors on linux servers***

Fix

```
if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT')  /* Linux fix */
    \File::delete($path.'\\'.$file);
else
    \File::delete($path.'/'.$file);
```